# Ubuntu Python Homebrew no module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, tkinter, homebrew

I have the issue with Python 3.9.1 on freshly installed Ubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) - when running any tkinter-based application, I get import error (example from python console):

```
user@ubuntu:~$ python3
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 29 2020, 13:25:02) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I know this issue was discussed multiple times in SO and other internet resources, for several days I am trying all the options and solutions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760839/why-my-python-installed-via-home-brew-not-include-tkinter), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424976/brew-install-python-matplotlib-not-working-no-module-named-tkinter), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481163/no-module-named-tkinter), [brew forum](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/python3-installation-with-tkinter/3636/3) neither of them solved the issue).
What works - only uninstalling homebrew does the trick. Still have hope to configure everything to work with homebrew.

What I have tried/performed:

- fixed all `brew doctor` reported issues:

```
Your system is ready to brew.
```

- tcl-tk is listed under `brew list`:

```
black  hello             libx11  libxdmcp  openssl@1.1  pylint      sqlite  xorgproto
bzip2  libffi            libxau  libxext   patchelf     python@3.9  tcl-tk  xz
gdbm   libpthread-stubs  libxcb  ncurses   pkg-config   readline    unzip   zlib
```

- performed `brew uninstall python` and `brew install python`
- Initial thought was poetry and/or pyenv broke the dependencies, currently using neither of them.

I am not hardcore ubuntu user, am I missing something? Any idea or help would be valuable.

Comment: why are you not using apt instead of homebrew

Comment: no hard reasons - just used to it in work environment on mac. It worked well, except the issue with tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew is not the official pcakage mamanger for ubuntu and has some strange behaviours ,Ubuntu's officialy supported pacakage manager that is installed by default is `apt`(advanced package tool)

**First uninstall your brew install of python by typing:**

`brew uninstall python`

**Then this is how you use APT to install python3:**

`sudo apt-get install python3`

OR

`sudo apt install python3`

**And to test if python3 installed correctly type:**

`python3`

If a python shell opens python3 has been installed properly

**Then to test if tkinter is working type this in the python shell:**

`import tkinter`

Comment: Thanks, tried it all already, I confirm, this works. Still trying to figure out how to work it out with homebrew.

Comment: Any other ideas, or suggestions would be welcome

Comment: Update: @TERMINATOR, just in case tried all the steps you have provided:  
* unistalled the python on with brew uninstall  
* installed python3 on ubuntu - it was installed already...  
* ran python3 - it gives the error that cannot find python on homebrew path:  
"user@ubuntu:~$ python3  
bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3: No such file or directory"  
Maybe any issue with environmental variables. Unless I unistall brew completely it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the question, as no other activity for over a week.
Used solution I wanted to avoid - removed homebrew, now Tkinter is detected properly.
For anyone stumbling on the same issue - uninstalling homebrew: https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew